# ASP.NET to have a text field in confirm window and use required field check for that

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

i am having a confirm window show in ASP.NET when clicking on a button and i do this in C# as below,

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "confirm", "ConfirmAccept();", true);
```

Then the confirm function is called in JavaScript as below,

```
function ConfirmAccept() {
    if (confirm("Do you confirm to add this entry?")) {
        var clickButton = document.getElementById("<%= button_add.ClientID %>");
        clickButton.click();
    }
}
```

Here when i click on the button and confirm box comes and when i press ok the code inside the `button_add` click is executed. But here i want to have a text box to show up in the confirm window and i want the enter a value before clicking OK on confirm box. This field should also have a required field check on clicking the OK button. Then after clicking OK i want to access this field's value or text inside the `button_add` click event. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you want this code..
If you do not want this.

i am so sorry.
my english skill is low.

.aspx

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>



<script type="text/javascript">
    function ConfirmAccess() {
        var result = prompt("Do you confirm to add this entry?", "");

        if (result == null) {
            alert("click cancel");
            return false;
        }
        alert("you enter this value : " + result);

        var hidConfirmValue = document.getElementById("<%=hidConfirmValue.ClientID%>");
        hidConfirmValue.value = result;

        var clickButton = document.getElementById("<%= btnAdd.ClientID %>");
        clickButton.click();
        return false;
    }
</script>


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidConfirmValue" />
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnConfirm" Text="Confirm" OnClientClick="return ConfirmAccess();"/>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAdd" Text="Add" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtResult"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

.cs

```
using System;

namespace StackoverflowWebForm
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtResult.Text = hidConfirmValue.Value;
        }
    }
}
```